# How can I see "idlers" count?

Tags: dwarf-fortress-premium

In classic Dwarf Fortress, there is a counter to know the number of idle dwarfs, but I can't find this information in the Premium/Steam version.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can see it.

Separately, apparently idler count hasn't worked properly since taverns were added.